# Is there examples of using the OPC UA spec part 14 Pub/Sub?

Tags: python, mqtt, publish-subscribe, opc-ua, opc

I am searching to do a program using part 14 of OPC UA to create an application. For now, I am coding in python. My current program uses the part 4 Subscription to have the value of a variable in a simulated PLC each time it changes, then a PubSub model with MQTT publishes a string with the new value which is read in another program to print it.

I understand that there is a way to do an OPC UA PubSub model but I don't know how to do it. Moreover, I saw that there is a way to construct the information to publish (mapping?) but I don't know if there is a function that does it automatically and what are the advantages of this method.

I would like to know if my way of doing is correct or if I missed something when I was searching on the internet. And do you know if there are examples that can inspire me?

Answer (score 0):

there is the following example of the OPC Foundation:
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-IIoT-StarterKit

Maybe this helps you.

Comment: here is another one: https://github.com/barnstee/MQTTPublisherMVP/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to subscribe to OPC UA PubSub messages over MQTT using [QuickOPC](https://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/python):

```py
    # This example shows how to subscribe to all dataset messages on an OPC-UA PubSub connection with MQTT JSON mapping using
    # TCP.
    #
    import opclabs_quickopc
    import opclabs_mqttnet
    import time
    
    # Import .NET namespaces.
    from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.UA.PubSub import *
    from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.UA.PubSub.Engine import *
    from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.UA.PubSub.OperationModel import *
    
    
    def dataSetMessage(sender, e):
        # Display the dataset.
        if e.Succeeded:
            # An event with null DataSetData just indicates a successful connection.
            if e.DataSetData is not None:
                print('')
                print('Dataset data: ', e.DataSetData, sep='')
                for pair in e.DataSetData.FieldDataDictionary:
                    print(pair)
        else:
            print('')
            print('*** Failure: ', e.ErrorMessageBrief, sep='')
            print('*** Failure: ', e.Exception, sep='')
    
    
    # Define the PubSub connection we will work with. Uses implicit conversion from a string.
    # Default port with MQTT is 1883.
    pubSubConnectionDescriptor = UAPubSubConnectionDescriptor.op_Implicit('mqtt://opcua-pubsub.demo-this.com')
    # Specify the transport protocol mapping.
    
    # Define the arguments for subscribing to the dataset, specifying the MQTT topic name.
    subscribeDataSetArguments = UASubscribeDataSetArguments(pubSubConnectionDescriptor)
    subscribeDataSetArguments.DataSetSubscriptionDescriptor.CommunicationParameters.BrokerDataSetReaderTransportParameters.\
        QueueName = 'opcuademo/json'
    
    # Instantiate the subscriber object and hook events.
    subscriber = EasyUASubscriber()
    subscriber.DataSetMessage += dataSetMessage
    
    print('Subscribing...')
    IEasyUASubscriberExtension.SubscribeDataSet(subscriber, subscribeDataSetArguments)
    
    print('Processing dataset message events for 20 seconds...')
    time.sleep(20)
    
    print('Unsubscribing...')
    subscriber.UnsubscribeAllDataSets()
    
    print('Waiting for 1 second...')
    # Unsubscribe operation is asynchronous, messages may still come for a short while.
    time.sleep(1)
    
    subscriber.DataSetMessage -= dataSetMessage
    
    print('Finished.')
```

Regarding the usage of the PubSub information model, it can be used to [resolve the connection/subscription information](https://opclabs.doc-that.com/files/onlinedocs/OPCLabs-OpcStudio/Latest/User%27s%20Guide%20and%20Reference-OPC%20Studio/webframe.html#OPC%20UA%20PubSub%20logical%20resolution.html) as well.